Optimize calculation of statistics over rows of a matrix in Python + Numba
I have a code which basically calculates the mean of the channels of each channel of an image.
Yet the mean is a robust mean calculated between quantiles and iqnores zero pixels (all channels value is 0):
import numpy as np
import skimage as ski
from numba import njit

image = ski.io.imread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikolalysenko/lena/master/lena.png")

def cal_img_stat( img: np.ndarray, low_quantile: float = 0.0, high_quantile: float = 1.0 ):

  num_px_channel = img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]

  chnl_matrix = np.reshape(np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1)), (3, num_px_channel)) # bottleneck
  non_zero_px_flag = np.any(chnl_matrix , axis=0) # ignore zero valued pixel
  non_zero_px = chnl_matrix[:, non_zero_px_flag]
  min_vals, max_vals = np.quantile(non_zero_px, [low_quantile, high_quantile], axis=1)

  mask_px = np.logical_and(non_zero_px >= min_vals[:, None], non_zero_px <= max_vals [:, None])
  mean_vals = np.mean(non_zero_px, axis = 1, where = mask_px)

  return mean_vals

mean_vals = cal_img_stat(image, 0.05, 0.95)


I tried to optimize the run time of the code:

apply the function along rows.
Pack the channels to be contiguous in memory.

In addition, I tried applying the actual mean calculation using numba hand crafted function. I also tried to write chnl_matrix = np.reshape(np.transpose(img, (2, 0, 1)), (3, num_px_channel)) using numba yet with no improvement.
It seems the bottleneck is the conversion of the image to matrix.
I could do a faster conversion by np.reshape(img, (num_px_channel, 3)) yet the following operations will be slower.
Is there a better policy to apply here to get a better run time?

I cannot reproduce the performance issue about the supposed bottleneck. The mentioned bottleneck takes 4 µs on my machine while the whole computation takes 33 ms... I expect a view to be created. If y explicitly create the array using .copy(), it takes only 0.3 ms which is only 1% of the computation time...

I think img is certainly not a contiguous array in your real-world use-case (or due to a different version of scikit maybe). What is actually img.strides when the code is slow? What is your version of Numpy?
